# Reference request: Integrability condition on measures

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, integration

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \|\cdot\|)$ be a (non-locally compact) Banach space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Given a probability measure $\mu : \mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]$, I'm interested in regularity (''growth'') conditions on $\mu$ which guarantee that

$$\tag{1}\|\mu\|:=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\!\|x\|\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x) \, < \, \infty.$$

Clearly, probability measures with bounded support are of this form, but clearly there must be a reference where (Fernique-like) conditions of the form $(1)$ are studied in greater generality?

Comment: These are Radon measures of order 1 from the theory of Radonifying mappings due to Laurent Schwartz. Described in many sources, many in French, some in English.

Comment: @user95282 Excellent, thank you!